# Qt C error duplicate symbol _function_names in juicy_lucy.o and main.o for architectures x86_64

Tags: c, qt

I am working on a C console project in Qt (Mac) because client does not want C++

With everything in a single C file everything was working well but, of course,
it started getting too big.

So I created a new juicy_lucy.h and juicy_lucy.c file and, to start with, just transferred some stuff from main.c to juicy_lucy.h which now looks like this

```
#ifndef JUICY_LUCY_H
#define JUICY_LUCY_H

#define command_count   14
char  *function_names[command_count] = {
                    "CLEAR_LCD", "PUT_LCD", "SET_VAR", "ADC_READ",
                    "BIT_WRITE", "BIT_READ", "BIT_WAIT",
                    "FAIL_LESS", "FAIL_MORE", "FAIL_HIGH","FAIL_LOW",
                    "AVR_PROG","AVR_READ_SERIAL","AVR_WRITE_SERIAL"
                     };
int   param_count[command_count] = {0,3,2,1,2,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1};
#endif // JUICY_LUCY_H
```

and, of course, include the header in both main.c and juicy_lucy.c

Now when I build I get

duplicate symbol _function_names in juicy_lucy.o and main.o for architectures x86_64

Can anybody suggest what may be wrong?

Comment: Are you redefining `function_names` in `main.c`?

Comment: nope. I cut the declaration from main.c and moved it to juicy_lucy.h

Comment: i guess if all is same as you are saying then u need a make clean(remove *.o) before next make.

Comment: My first thought was putting include guards in your header file, but I see you have that there. If you really don't have duplicate functions anywhere else, I would agree with @Dayalrai, try cleaning the build and removing all object files.

Comment: OK - found it. But crazy.

The variable function_names is actually being included in main and juicy_lucy so I really do have duplicates of the variable.

I think that the guards are ignored in C - only used in C++.
I could be wrong - never really did big C projects.

When I did the rest of the migration and moved the functions across
I could move the variables into juicy_lucy.c and all was well.

Answer (score 1):

You must declare function_names as

```
const char* const function_names[] = ...
```

Then the symbol function_names should not appear twice in your linked application.

Answer (score 1):

In your .h:

```
extern char *function_names[command_count];
extern int param_count[command_count];
```

In *one* of your .c files:

```
char  *function_names[command_count] = {
                    "CLEAR_LCD", "PUT_LCD", "SET_VAR", "ADC_READ",
                    "BIT_WRITE", "BIT_READ", "BIT_WAIT",
                    "FAIL_LESS", "FAIL_MORE", "FAIL_HIGH","FAIL_LOW",
                    "AVR_PROG","AVR_READ_SERIAL","AVR_WRITE_SERIAL"
                     };
int   param_count[command_count] = {0,3,2,1,2,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1};
```